# What is blocking the FTP and HTTP traffic on XP with Windows Firewall disabled?

Tags: windows-xp, ftp, firewall, http

I've just had to reinstall the drivers for the D-Link G510 wireless card on an XP machine as they were causing a BSOD. It now successfully connects to the internet as I can ping and tracert to www.google.com with no problems but it won't browse the internet.

The connection is managed with the Windows WZC service and using the diagnostics it tells me that the traffic on ports 80 and 443 are blocked which certainly explains why we can't browse but there isn't anything that should be blocking those ports. Other machines on the same connection browse fine so I don't think it's anything on the router.

I've disabled the Windows firewall but the ports are still blocked. I also tried enabling the firewall and added an exception for IE8 but still no joy. The only other thing we did was uninstall Norton AV using the uninstall link in the start menu which completed successfully. There was also some other VPN software that we no longer needed and uninstalled. There are suggestions on other forums that Norton doesn't actually uninstall properly but I've checked the file system and the registry and couldn't see any obvious traces. There was a Norton Security Filter service running but I stopped that and disabled it but that didn't make a difference either.

Curiously the automated updates are downloading but the diagnostic reports says that FTP is blocked as well as HTTP and HTTPS. I can only assume they use another port or have been allowed access.

How can I make sure all traces of Norton are definitely removed and then find and disable whatever it is that is blocking the HTTP, HTTPS and FTP ports?

Answer (score 1):

Once you uninstall Norton, it'll remove the network driver. Since that is removed, all the rules are ineffective whether they are saved somewhere on the PC or not. What about checking all the running applications with the [Sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) ? First I'd go with `procexp` to check for any not neccessary active proccess since those can also block such access. Don't forget to check the other tools.

If we go other way around: Does the internet works with LAN connection? Check for other network 'devices' or drivers in the "Device Manager". Firewalls always have a 'driver' what they install .. its a layer between the net and the PC basically.

Comment: Thanks, will give the SysInternals a go as I was also wondering if there was a rootkit somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen malware cause this, Doing a IE reset cures it after the malware is removed.

This works even if you don't use IE as your browser.